# MySQL - Select something ONLY where columns contain specific values, and nothing else

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements

I have a messages_users table that contains users participating to a conversation :

`conversationId | userId`

Since the purpose is that multiple users can get in a conversation, one row equals one user.

There are two types of conversations : conversation with friend, and grouped conversation with multiple users. What distincts them is only the number of people in it.

2 users = conversation with friend

3 or more = grouped conversation

I want to allow users to open a conversation with their friends from their ids (here, 1 and 2). So, I need to make a SQL statement that will retrive a conversation id ONLY where those two users are in.

If I do this, I'll get every conversations that those two users are in (if there are grouped conversations with them, for example)

```
SELECT convId FROM messages_users WHERE userId IN (1,2)
```

I tried this but it won't work :

```
SELECT convId FROM messages_users WHERE userId IN (1,2) HAVING COUNT(userId) = 2
```

Also tried this, but still it will get me every conversations they are in :

```
SELECT convId FROM messages_users a INNER JOIN messages_users b ON a.convId = b.convId WHERE a.userId = 1 AND b.userId = 2
```

Comment: Try adding `group by convId` to your second query...

Comment: My second query, as it is, won't return anything. If I add group by statement, it will get every conversations as well

Comment: Look at the solutions below.  `Group by` will not return all the conversations since you have `where` criteria as well.  And the `having` statement is what checks to see if you have 2 users or not...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition that you want is:

```
SELECT mu.convId
FROM messages_users mu
GROUP BY mu.convId
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN mu.userId = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN mu.userId = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN mu.userId NOT IN (1, 2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

You can't filter *before* the `GROUP BY` because then you would miss counting user "3" if in the conversation.  The third condition prevents "3" from participating.

In MySQL, this can be simplified to:

```
SELECT mu.convId
FROM messages_users mu
GROUP BY mu.convId
HAVING SUM( mu.userId = 1 ) > 0 AND
       SUM( mu.userId = 2 ) > 0 AND
       SUM( mu.userId NOT IN (1, 2) ) = 0;
```

Comment: Is it only for mysql that you can do it without the Case/When ?

Comment: @DanielE. . . . Some other databases have short-cuts, but the syntax might be slightly different.  The general method is to use `case` expressions.

Comment: Thank you, this does the job and it seems to be the fastest approach among other solutions suggested. Though, could you tell me why the condition has to be wrapped into a SUM() statement? It will return 0 or 1 anyway, so, why?

Comment: @Snyte . . . The `HAVING` clause is evaluated after the `GROUP BY`.  It is counting the number of rows in each group where the given conditions are true.  Hence, it needs to use an aggregation function.

Answer (score 2):

We can try using a self-join operation with an `EXISTS` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT mu1.convId
FROM messages_users mu1
INNER JOIN messages_users mu2
    ON mu1.convId = mu2.convId
WHERE
    (mu1.userId = 1 AND mu2.userId = 2) AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM messages_users mu
                WHERE mu.convId = mu1.convId AND userID NOT IN (1, 2));
```

Here is a link to a demo showing that the above logic works:

### Demo

Comment: Tried this, but unfortunatly it stills returns every conversations. I have conversation 1 that contains 1 and 2 users only, and conversation 2 that contains 1 and 2 users plus a third one. Everytime, I get conversation id 1 and 2

Answer (score 1):

For every "*conversation with friend*" there must be only 2 rows with the same `convId`:

```
SELECT convId
FROM messages_users 
GROUP BY convId
HAVING COUNT(userId) = 2;
```

If you want the "*conversations with friend*" for users 1 and 2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT convId FROM messages_users 
WHERE 
  (userId IN (1, 2)) 
  AND 
  convId IN 
    (SELECT convId
    FROM messages_users 
    GROUP BY convId
    HAVING COUNT(userId) = 2);
```

See [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hvcUruzDgS9BQKrxE1CXBf/0)

Comment: Thanks, it does work. I like the simplicity of your query

Comment: It's not only about the simplicity, but also about the flexibility, as there is only 1 change you need to make: `IN (?, ?)`, in order to get results for any pair of users.